# ABGroupAddMember does not work on iOS4 device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, addressbook

the code bellow works great in Simulator (both iOS 4 and 5) but adds no contact on the iOS 4 device. No error is returned. Do you have any idea why?

```
ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
abGroupRef = ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID(ab, 1);
ABRecordRef pRef = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ab, 1);
ABGroupAddMember(abGroupRef, pRef, &anError);
ABAddressBookSave(ab, &anError);
```

Thanks,
--Josef

Comment: Remember that *both* `ABGroupAddMember` and `AbAddressBookSave` return BOOL values of YES if their functions were successful. One of them is likely returning `NO`, in which case you can then check the error on that.

Comment: It is true that I don't check the return value, but I always check the anError which is not in my code above (better readability). The anError is always NULL thus I assume no error occurred. Is it good assumption? Even if I know that ABGroupAddMember has returned NO, what do I know if the anError is NULL? Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the contacts were from google synced by exchange. There can be only local groups and local groups may only hold local contacts. This is kinda fair but the ABGroupAddMember should return an error if it is not going to add the member.

Comment: Hi devZone.touchDude.com I am facing the same problem Adding contacts to group working proprly on simulator but not on iPhone device What solution you found for this problem Plzz Share

Comment: In my case the root case was using the exchange synced contacts. These may not use groups (at least at the time of doing this could not). So I stopped relying on groups and implemented my own -> not realy a fix for you, right?

Answer (score 1):

It's good Objective C programming practice to always check the result of a function that returns a BOOL value (such as `ABGroupAddMember` or `ABAddressBookSave` or the `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` `writeToFile` methods) ***before*** checking to see if there is an error returned as one of the parameters.

Try something like this instead:

```
ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef abGroupRef = ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID(ab, 1);
ABRecordRef pRef = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ab, 1);
CFErrorRef anError = NULL;
NSError * anErrorAsObjectiveCObject; // for use with toll free bridged object magic

if(ABGroupAddMember(abGroupRef, pRef, &anError))
{
    if(ABAddressBookSave(ab, &anError))
    {
        NSLog(@"successfully saved");
    } else {
        anErrorAsObjectiveCObject = (__bridge_transfer NSError *) anError;
        NSLog( @"error in ABAddressBookSave - %@ %@", [anErrorAsObjectiveCObject domain], [anErrorAsObjectiveCObject localizedDescription] );
    }
} else {
    anErrorAsObjectiveCObject = (__bridge_transfer NSError *) anError;
    NSLog( @"error in ABGroupAddMember - %@ %@", [anErrorAsObjectiveCObject domain], [anErrorAsObjectiveCObject localizedDescription] );
}
```

Comment: Well, as I wrote in the previous comment, I do this but the error is null. Your code returns this "error in ABGroupAddMember - (null) (null)". So I know that it did not work, I just don't know why :-(

Comment: are `abGroupRef` or `pRef` not null when they go into the `ABGroupAddMember` function ?

Comment: both not null: abGroupRef:<CPRecord: 0x4b645a0 ABGroup> pRef:<CPRecord: 0x4b64cd0 ABPerson>. This very same code works in simulator like a charm.

Comment: Do I need some special settings for the &anError to work? Either compilation settings or on iPhone? It seems that it never returns a value.

Comment: Hi  devZone.touchDude.com  I am facing the same problem
Adding contacts to group working proprly on simulator but not on iPhone device
What solution you found for this problem
Plzz Share