# iPhone: Adding contact to a group not working on device but working on simulator in ABAddressbook

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

Adding contact to a group not working on device but working on simulator in ABAddressbook
Gives no error but contact is not reflected in particular group in contacts
but works fine on Simulator

I am Using this code

```
if (person) {
           ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, nil);

           ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);

           BOOL isADDED = ABGroupAddMember(groupNameRef, person, &error);

           NSError *error1 = (__bridge_transfer NSError *)error;

           NSLog(@"Reason = %@", error1.localizedFailureReason);
           BOOL iSSaved = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
}
```

works fine on Simulator but not on device

Comment: Your error-checking is all wrong. Fix it, and then use it to learn what is going wrong on the device.

Comment: Error is printing null
But there is no problem on simulator

Comment: Error is printing null because your error checking is all wrong.

Comment: You can't test address book commands on simulator. Test only on device.

Comment: Can you Please help me in printing error message
or any other code to save contact in a group in ABAddressbook
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Also this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525360/abgroupaddmember-does-not-work-on-ios4-device

Answer (score 2):

It will help you to start by using error-checking correctly. Here is the structure of an error-checked routine:

```
if (person) {
    bool ok;
    CFErrorRef err = nil;
    ok = ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, &err);
    if (!ok) {
        NSLog(@"%@", err);
        return;
    }
    ok = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &err);
    if (!ok) {
        NSLog(@"%@", err);
        return;
    }
    ok = ABGroupAddMember(groupNameRef, person, &err);
    if (!ok) {
        NSLog(@"%@", err);
        return;
    }
    ok = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &err);
    if (!ok) {
        NSLog(@"%@", err);
        return;
    }
}
```

Notice the pattern here. The function returns a bool. You examine that bool. If it is false, then you examine the error returned by indirection. If you follow this pattern correctly, you will get better information about what is going wrong.

**Edit**: Make sure you actually have access to the contacts database. I'm assuming you do, but a major difference between the Simulator and the device is that the Simulator grants access automatically, whereas on the device the user must be presented with the access request dialog (call `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion`) or else there won't be access and attempts to work with the contacts database will fail, perhaps silently.